# Two divs side by side with flex

Tags: html, css

I have 4 cells in laptops mode And when I want to have two cells side by side in phone mode I have to remove the flex in the outer div But I can no longer have an auto height div . How to fix this

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
}
.cell {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove `flex`? Could you not do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8wgyc1be/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use 2 more css attribute, flex and flex-wrap.

To ensure the cell wrap to the next line when the screen is too small, you must add the property `flex-wrap : wrap` to the row class.

Then you need to define a `flex` property for the cell.

The `flex` property is defined like that

```
flex : flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis;
```

Flex-grow and flex-shrink are grow and shrink coefficient. Here, all the cell must have the same width, so we do not care about this value (I've set these to 1).
Flex-basis indicate the default width of your cell

Here's an example :

```css
.box {
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.cell {
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```